# Poweshell retrieve sql query result

Tags: sql, powershell

I am quite new to PowerShell. I have multiple SQL queries which I am executing from a PS script using SQL adapter. I need to retrieve the common results based on a column from the queries without changing existing queries or writing another one. How to achieve this with PowerShell using the results stored in a variable?
I've tried working around with rows[x],columns[y] but it doesn't work and writing the names of the columns every time is difficult for big results.

I am storing the results this way:

```
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$Dataset = New-Object System.Data.Dataset
$SqlAdapter.Fill($Dataset)
$DataSet.Tables[0]
```

Suppose query 1 results:

```
 names   type1  id1
 pk1     t1   26
 pk3     t5   25
 pk26    t5   36 
 pk11    t1   99
```

query 2 results:

```
 names  type2  id2
 pk11   t9   2699
 pk1    t7   252
 pk136  t9   368 
 pk8    t5   9
```

I need the common one's from both results based on the names column which I will further save in a file. (Edited the output as it wasn't in right format)

```
 names   type1  id1 type2 id2
 pk1     t1     26  t7    252
 pk11    t1     99  t9    2699
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, PowerShell's [Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.1) coupled with array indexing can achieve this goal.

```
# Objects with query results
$q1 = @'
names,type,id
pk1,t1,26
pk3,t5,25
pk26,t5,36
pk11,t1,99
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$q2 = @'
names,type,id
pk11,t9,2699
pk1,t7,252
pk136,t9,368
pk8,t5,9
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

0..1 | Foreach-Object {
    $i = $_ # Index of each grouped item
    # Looking for count = 2 to find matches from both queries
    $q1 + $q2 | Group names | Where Count -eq 2 | Foreach-Object {
        # i = 0 is common objects from $q1
        # i = 1 is common objects from $q2
        $_.Group[$i]
    } | Export-Csv Results$i.csv -NoType
}
```

`Results0.csv` will contain the first table results. `Results1.csv` will contain the second table results.

`Group-Object` groups objects based on grouped properties. Grouping on `names` will put all objects with the same `names` value into a `GroupInfo` object accessible by the `Group` property. The `Group` property is a collection with indexed items. The first item in each grouping (`[0]` item) will be the first object read. So as long as `$q1` and `$q2` share a value, then `[0]` item will always be from `$q1` because we send `$q1` into the pipeline first from expression `$q1 + $q2`. Correspondingly, `[1]` will contain `$q2` items.

---

Edit 1: You updated your question with table column names with a different requirement.

```
# Objects with query results
$q1 = @'
names,type1,id1
pk1,t1,26
pk3,t5,25
pk26,t5,36
pk11,t1,99
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$q2 = @'
names,type2,id2
pk11,t9,2699
pk1,t7,252
pk136,t9,368
pk8,t5,9
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$q1+$q2 | Group-Object names |
    where count -eq 2 | Foreach-Object {
        $hash = [ordered]@{}
        $_.Group | Foreach-Object {
            $_.psobject.properties | Foreach-Object {
                $hash[$_.Name] = $_.Value
            }
        }
    [pscustomobject]$hash
    } | Export-Csv results.csv -NoType
```

Comment: Thanks! the `GroupObject` works really well. But is there a way I can get this grouped output i.e `q1` and `q2` in a single file insted of `[0] [1]` ? I've written a script to merge these files but it is quite troublesome. Also my headers are different, I've updated it.

Comment: @Mayhan I added another script to handle your updated/changed question.